# thyroid gland and bodybuilding

Tags: nutrition, bodybuilding

I've talked a litte bit with an old bodybuilder and he says to me : "If you really want to gain weight you must stop eating 'sugar' and milk before arround 5pm," by sugar he meant fruits etc

"because sugar and milk wake up your thyroid gland and it will waste your kcalorie income for keeping your facial features etc"

He said that because i'm this kind of ectomorph.

**Someone know that and helps me to understand deeper what he meant ?**

Answer (score 1):

Well, I certainly applaud anyone wanting to cut down their sugar intake to below 100 grams after 5pm, but take it from this old gym rat, I've spent my entire adult life in the gym, and nutrition like this can do more harm than good.

If you only eat one type of carb (and that's all a eating a single complex carb is going to do for you), you're setting yourself up for different somatotypes down the road. I've seen it a hundred times.

It's like putting a powerful engine in a stock Toyota Tercel. What will you accomplish? You'll blow out the drive train, the clutch, the transmission, etc., because those factory parts aren't designed to handle the power of an engine much more powerful than the factory installed engine.

Complex carbs basically only fuel some of your thighroid gland and to some extent, your glycogen stores. What you really want to do is eat every type of carb, all the major carbohydrates (monosaccharides, oligosaccharides, and polysaccharides) at the same time, over the course of the day. And don't forget your sugars too!

I'm proud of you wanting to do this. Three cheers! Falling in love with exercise, eating right, etc., is one of the greatest things you can do for yourself. And you WILL fall in love with it if you can just force yourself to stick with it a year or two and experience the amazing progress you'll make.

But do it right, okay?

Comment: So, basically, you suggest to cut down my simple carbohydrates by eating more food containing complex carbs like potatoes, beans, carrots, whole bread/pasta... ? 

I've seen [here](http://www.3fatchicks.com/5-foods-with-complex-carbohydrates/) some food that may help me to reach this this kind of objectives.

Answer (score 0):

The clue in your question is "old bodybuilder" = old ideas about nutrition based on old science. However, modern nutrition does support some reasons you may not want to eat sugars (and milk also has lots of natural sugar) after 5pm, as high-sugar foods affect your insulin levels and high-insulin levels are shown to affect the body's hormones (the thyroid being the producer of the thyroid hormone).

As an athlete, you definitely want to make sure you are eating healthy, BALANCED meals and snacks that include the right kind of protein, carbs and fats in the proper proportion.

If you do that, you won't have to worry about old-(bodybuilder)-tales when it comes to nutrition.

Comment: Please specify what constitutes "balanced" and "right kind", and "proper proportion".